# How do I insert data in two different entitys within one method?

Tags: iphone, core-data

I am pretty new to coredata. My goal is to write data into to different entitys within one function. I've initialized coredata in my application delegate and pass it to my viewcontroller. In my viewController I want to decide situation-dependend, which entity should be used. So I edited the code of the fetchedResultsController-method like so:

```
-(NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsControllerForEntityWithString:(NSString*)theEntityString {
...
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:theEntityString inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
...
}
```

The second method I was altering is saveContext:

```
-(void)saveContextForEntityWithString:(NSString*)theEntityString {
    NSManagedObjectContext *contex = [self fetchedResultsControllerForEntityWithString:theEntityString managedObjectContext];
...
}
```

For inserting new data I wrote a new method:

```
-(void)insertEntityForString:(NSString*)theEntityName {
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[self fetchedResultsControllerForEntityWithString:theEntityName] managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [[[self fetchedResultsControllerForEntityWithString:theEntityName] fetchRequest] entity];
NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];

if ([newManagedObject isKindOfClass:[myClass1 class]]) {
    newManagedObject.testValue:[NSDate date];
} else if ([newManagedObject isKindOfClass:[myClass2 class]]) {

}
```

}

Unfortunately this approach won't be successful. Xcode won't know whether testValue exists and throws me an error.

Hopefully you can help me getting better in understanding how coredata should be set up properly.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This test:

```
if ([newManagedObject isKindOfClass:[myClass1 class]]) {
```

... is always going to fail because this line:

```
NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

... always defines `newManagedObject` as of class `NSManagedObject`.

It is common to confuse entites, the NSManagedObject class and NSManagedObject subclasses.

Entities are abstraction akin to class definitions. They tell the managed object context how the data in the object is to be structured.

NSManagedObject is confusing because any generic instance of NSManagedObject can store data from any entity using associative storage. Associative storage works like a dictionary. The entity provides the keys to the dictionary. So, a line like this:

```
NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

... inserts a generic NSManagedObject instance into the context and then sets the key name of its associative storage to the names define by the entity. The class of the object is always NSManagedObject regardless of what entity provides its keys.

You only see a different class when you create a subclass of NSManagedObject which is locked into a specific entity. The key names of the entity become the defined attributes of the class.

I don't know exactly what you are shooting for in your design by shifting fetchedResultControllers. Normally, this produces a very confusing interface as users expect a single table to present the same data. Normally, you would use different tables to present data from different entities so that the users can orient themselves to the changes in data.

However, if you still want to do it the simplest method would be to define a `currentEntity` attribute for your tableview controller. Like so:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain)  NSString *currentEntity;
```

... then add a test to your fetchedResultsController getter method:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        if ([[[fetchedResultsController entity] name] isEqualToString:self.currentEntity]) {
            return fetchedResultsController;
        }
    }
    // configure the FRC as normal but for the fetch entity name use currentEntity
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:self.currentEntity inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    //....
```

Now, to change entities for the controllers fetch, you just need to change the name stored in `currentEntity`. The next time the FRC is called, it will automatically be reset to the new entity fetch.

However, I've got to warn you that the FRC and the associated table methods are not really setup for swapping like this. You will have to be careful with the table updates and I don't think it will be reliable or stable.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for your great explanation! I've got an app which is "seperated" into two parts: parking in a parking garage and parking outside. So I defined an entity for every part: http://img64.imageshack.us/i/bildschirmfoto20110227u.png/ So do you think I schould design my model in an other way? As I said I am really new to core data and want to learn as much as possible :)

Answer (score 0):

`newManagedObject.testValue:[NSDate date];`

is the `:` a typo that happened when you modified the code for the question?

and you can always use setValue:forKey: to set the attribute of a core data object. 
Like

```
[newManagedObject setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"testValue];
```

---

another option would be an abstract entity and its object that you would use as super class in the class of your two entities

Comment: Oh yep, just a misspelling. Thanks for your answer. So do you think my code is a good startingpoint?

Answer (score 0):

If you've defined myClass1 and myClass2 as subclasses you can do eomthing like this:

```
-(void)insertEntityForString:(NSString*)theEntityName {
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[self fetchedResultsControllerForEntityWithString:theEntityName] managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [[[self fetchedResultsControllerForEntityWithString:theEntityName] fetchRequest] entity];
NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];

if ([newManagedObject isKindOfClass:[myClass1 class]]) {
    myClass1 *newMyClass1 = (myClass1)newManagedObject;
    newMyClass1.testValue = [NSDate date];
} else if ([newManagedObject isKindOfClass:[myClass2 class]]) {
    myClass2 *newMyClass2 = (myClass2)newManagedObject;
    newMyClass2.someOtherValue = @"Hi, Hello";
}
```

If not, your if statement would look like this:

```
if ([newManagedObject isKindOfClass:[myClass1 class]]) {
    [newManagedObject setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"testValue"];
} else if ([newManagedObject isKindOfClass:[myClass2 class]]) {
    [newManagedObject setValue:@"Hi, Hello" forKey:@"someOtherName"];
}
```